# Unwanted Logs in Jenkins for extent reports com.aventstack.extentreports.model.Test

Tags: selenium, jenkins, extent

I have recently implemented Extent reports in my project.
I am seeing strange logs in the console , this caused TEST-TestSuite.xml size to grow about 1 GB.
I have tried to set the System property but it didnt worked *System.setProperty("org.freemarker.loggerLibrary", "none");*

Some Example of logs

com.aventstack.extentreports.model.Log.getExceptionInfo()=[Ljava.lang.Class;@7034bb18, public com.aventstack.extentreports.model.AbstractStructure com.aventstack.extentreports.model.Log.getScreenCaptureContext()=[Ljava.lang.Class;@7bf5bd4f, public void com.aventstack.extentreports.model.Log.setExceptionInfo(com.aventstack.extentreports.model.ExceptionInfo)=[Ljava.lang.Class;@5fb27796, public void com.aventstack.extentreports.model.Log.setSequence(int)=[Ljava.lang.Class;@4263f02f, public com.aventstack.extentreports.model.Test com.aventstack.extentreports.model.Log.getTest()=[Ljava.lang.Class;@175a6f00, public com.aventstack.extentreports.Status com.aventstack.extentreports.model.Log.getStatus()=[Ljava.lang.Class;@4113a761, public org.bson.types.ObjectId com.aventstack.extentreports.model.Log.getObjectId()=[Ljava.lang.Class;@dd17612, public void com.aventstack.extentreports.model.Log.setStatus(com.aventstack.extentreports.Status)=[Ljava.lang.Class;@506e1d0f, public final native java.lang.Class java.lang.Object.getClass()=[Ljava.lang.Class;@14085a6d, public void com.aventstack.extentreports.model.Log.setObjectId(org.bson.types.ObjectId)=[Ljava.lang.Class;@487cdf22, public java.lang.String com.aventstack.extentreports.model.Log.getDetails()=[Ljava.lang.Class;@4e9b51d9}, sequence=freemarker.ext.beans.FastPropertyDescriptor@6e3dab60, setScreenCaptureContext=public void com.aventstack.extentreports.model.Log.setScreenCaptureContext(com.aventstack.extentreports.model.AbstractStructure), equals=public boolean java.lang.Object.equals(java.lang.Object), toString=public java.lang.String java.lang.Object.toString(), getSequence=public int com.aventstack.extentreports.model.Log.getSequence(), exceptionInfo=freemarker.ext.beans.FastPropertyDescriptor@38b05ff8, status=freemarker.ext.beans.FastPropertyDescriptor@169b0203}
DEBUG   15960   [freemark] (): Key "stepName" was not found on instance of com.aventstack.extentreports.model.Log. Introspection information for the class is: {setSequence=public void com.aventstack.extentreports.model.Log.setSequence(int), setExceptionInfo=public void com.aventstack.extentreports.model.Log.setExceptionInfo(com.aventstack.extentreports.model.ExceptionInfo), getClass=public final native java.lang.Class java.lang.Object.getClass(), setTest=public void com.aventstack.extentreports.model.Log.setTest(com.aventstack.extentreports.model.Test), getScreenCaptureContext=public com.aventstack.extentreports.model.AbstractStructure com.aventstack.extentreports.model.Log.getScreenCaptureContext(), setObjectId=public void com.aventstack.extentreports.model.Log.setObjectId(org.bson.types.ObjectId), getStatus=public com.aventstack.extentreports.Status com.aventstack.extentreports.model.Log.getStatus(), getTest=public com.aventstack.extentreports.model.Test com.aventstack.extentreports.model.Log.getTest(), getObjectId=public org.bson.types.ObjectId com.aventstack.extentreports.model.Log.getObjectId(), screenCaptureContext=freemarker.ext.beans.FastPropertyDescriptor@5308bcc5, getTimestamp=public java.util.Date com.aventstack.extentreports.model.Log.getTimestamp(), hashCode=public native int java.lang.Object.hashCode(), setDetails=public void com.aventstack.extentreports.model.Log.setDetails(java.lang.String), java.lang.Object@baf2078=freemarker.ext.beans.SimpleMethod@220fb5bf, details=freemarker.ext.beans.FastPropertyDescriptor@4ba19f19, class=freemarker.ext.beans.FastPropertyDescriptor@40cb109d, objectId=freemarker.ext.beans.FastPropertyDescriptor@56b362d5, setTimestamp=public void com.aventstack.extentreports.model.Log.setTimestamp(java.util.Date), timestamp=freemarker.ext.beans.FastPropertyDescriptor@9ce97f1, test=freemarker.ext.beans.FastPropertyDescriptor@4e509886, getExceptionInfo=public com.aventstack.extentreports.model.ExceptionInfo com.aventstack.extentreports.model.Log.getExceptionInfo(), getDetails=public java.lang.String com.aventstack.extentreports.model.Log.getDetails(), setStatus=public void com.aventstack.extentreports.model.Log.setStatus(com.aventstack.extentreports.Status), java.lang.Object@2cc5f775={public java.lang.String java.lang.Object.toString()=[Ljava.lang.Class;@56073629, public void com.aventstack.extentreports.model.Log.setScreenCaptureContext(com.aventstack.extentreports.model.AbstractStructure)=[Ljava.lang.Class;@1bef43f6, public void com.aventstack.extentreports.model.Log.setDetails(java.lang.String)=[Ljava.lang.Class;@66e33e65, public java.util.Date com.aventstack.extentreports.model.Log.getTimestamp()=[Ljava.lang.Class;@2c3d1e97, public int com.aventstack.extentreports.model.Log.getSequence()=[Ljava.lang.Class;@4364c347, public void com.aventstack.extentreports.model.Log.setTimestamp(java.util.Date)=[Ljava.lang.Class;@2275c82e, public native int java.lang.Object.hashCode()=[Ljava.lang.Class;@5d9ada13, public boolean java.lang.Object.equals(java.lang.Object)=[Ljava.lang.Class;@1917be91, public void com.aventstack.extentreports.model.Log.setTest(com.aventstack.extentreports.model.Test)=[Ljava.lang.Class;@7c0c380f, public com.aventstack.extentreports.model.ExceptionInfo com.aventstack.extentreports.model.Log.getExceptionInfo()=[Ljava.lang.Class;@7034bb18, public com.aventstack.extentreports.model.AbstractStructure com.aventstack.extentreports.model.Log.getScreenCaptureContext()=[Ljava.lang.Class;@7bf5bd4f, public void com.aventstack.extentreports.model.Log.setExceptionInfo(com.aventstack.extentreports.model.ExceptionInfo)=[Ljava.lang.Class;@5fb27796, public void com.aventstack.extentreports.model.Log.setSequence(int)=[Ljava.lang.Class;@4263f02f, public com.aventstack.extentreports.model.Test com.aventstack.extentreports.model.Log.getTest()=[Ljava.lang.Class;@175a6f00, public com.aventstack.extentreports.Status com.aventstack.extentreports.model.Log.getStatus()=[Ljava.lang.Class;@4113a761, public org.bson.types.ObjectId com.aventstack.extentreports.model.Log.getObjectId()=[Ljava.lang.Class;@dd17612, public void com.aventstack.extentreports.model.Log.setStatus(com.aventstack.extentreports.Status)=[Ljava.lang.Class;@506e1d0f, public final native java.lang.Class java.lang.Object.getClass()=[Ljava.lang.Class;@14085a6d, public void com.aventstack.extentreports.model.Log.setObjectId(org.bson.types.ObjectId)=[Ljava.lang.Class;@487cdf22, public java.lang.String com.aventstack.extentreports.model.Log.getDetails()=[Ljava.lang.Class;@4e9b51d9}, sequence=freemarker.ext.beans.FastPropertyDescriptor@6e3dab60, setScreenCaptureContext=public void com.aventstack.extentreports.model.Log.setScreenCaptureContext(com.aventstack.extentreports.model.AbstractStructure), equals=public boolean java.lang.Object.equals(java.lang.Object), toString=public java.lang.String java.lang.Object.toString(), getSequence=public int com.aventstack.extentreports.model.Log.getSequence(), exceptionInfo=freemarker.ext.beans.FastPropertyDescriptor@38b05ff8, status=freemarker.ext.beans.FastPropertyDescriptor@169b0203}
DEBUG   15960   [freemark] (): Key "stepName" was not found on instance of com.aventstack.extentreports.model.Log. Introspection information for the class is: {setSequence=public void com.aventstack.extentreports.model.Log.setSequence(int), setExceptionInfo=public void com.aventstack.extentreports.model.Log.setExceptionInfo(com.aventstack.extentreports.model.ExceptionInfo), getClass=public final native java.lang.Class java.lang.Object.getClass(), setTest=public void com.aventstack.extentreports.model.Log.setTest(com.aventstack.extentreports.model.Test), getScreenCaptureContext=public com.aventstack.extentreports.model.AbstractStructure com.aventstack.extentreports.model.Log.getScreenCaptureContext(), setObjectId=public void com.aventstack.extentreports.model.Log.setObjectId(org.bson.types.ObjectId), getStatus=public com.aventstack.extentreports.Status com.aventstack.extentreports.model.Log.getStatus(), getTest=public com.aventstack.extentreports.model.Test com.aventstack.extentreports.model.Log.getTest(), getObjectId=public org.bson.types.ObjectId com.aventstack.extentreports.model.Log.getObjectId(), screenCaptureContext=freemarker.ext.beans.FastPropertyDescriptor@5308bcc5, getTimestamp=public java.util.Date com.aventstack.extentreports.model.Log.getTimestamp(), hashCode=public native int java.lang.Object.hashCode(), setDetails=public void com.aventstack.extentreports.model.Log.setDetails(java.lang.String), java.lang.Object@baf2078=freemarker.ext.beans.SimpleMethod@220fb5bf, details=freemarker.ext.beans.FastPropertyDescriptor@4ba19f19, class=freemarker.ext.beans.FastPropertyDescriptor@40cb109d, objectId=freemarker.ext.beans.FastPropertyDescriptor@56b362d5, setTimestamp=public void com.aventstack.extentreports.model.Log.setTimestamp(java.util.Date), timestamp=freemarker.ext.beans.FastPropertyDescriptor@9ce97f1, test=freemarker.ext.beans.FastPropertyDescriptor@4e509886, getExceptionInfo=public com.aventstack.extentreports.model.ExceptionInfo com.aventstack.extentreports.model.Log.getExceptionInfo(), getDetails=public java.lang.String com.aventstack.extentreports.model.Log.getDetails(), setStatus=public void

Answer (score 0):

Resolved the issue by updating extent reports to version 5.1